# SQL: Get all rows with value n associated with id

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have the following tables cart, cart_data and product:

### Cart

**cart_id**
total_cost

### cart_data

**cart_data_id**
**cart_id**
**product_id**

### product

**product_id**
product_name

I'm trying to select all carts where each product_id in cart_data must = 2 and then return the cart_id where all product_ids = 2

For example:
If the cart has 5 products that all have id = 2 then the cart_id should show.

However, if the cart has 5 products that has 4 products = 2 and 1 product = 4 then it shouldn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it but this should work:

```
SELECT     cart_data.cart_id
FROM       cart_data
WHERE      cart_data.cart_id IN
           ( SELECT cart_data.cart_id
             FROM   cart_data
             GROUP BY cart_data.cart_id
             HAVING MIN( cart_data.product_id ) = 2
             AND    MAX( cart_data.product_id ) = 2
           )
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the quick reply! I really appreciate the help. There's just one small problem though, product table doesn't contain cart_data_id :(